# How to setup a Unity Registration Convention?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

With structure map, you can register a convention that lets you not just tweak the type, but also intervene during object creation.  How can I do this with Unity.

```
public class SettingsRegistration : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (!type.IsAbstract && typeof(ISettings).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            registry.For(type).Use(x =>
            {
                var svc = x.GetInstance<ISettingService>();
                return svc.LoadSetting(type);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of Unity's [Registration by Convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507479(v=pandp.30).aspx) and an [InjectionFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff661868(v=pandp.30).aspx).  I see three common options for implementation, though I'm sure there are more...

---

### Option 1

Register all type at once with if conditions inline in a lambda expression.  Though this does not scale well if you are registering many types with many custom registrations...

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.Transient,
    type =>
    {
        // If settings type, load the setting
        if (!type.IsAbstract && typeof (ISettings).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new InjectionFactory((c, t, n) =>
                {
                    var svc = (ISettings) c.Resolve(t);
                    return svc.LoadSetting(t);
                })
            };
        }

        // Otherwise, no special consideration is needed
        return new InjectionMember[0];
    });
```

---

### Option 2

Register only the ISettings types and supply some nice helper methods.  You will need to call container.RegisterTypes multiple times, but it is much more readable...

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().IsSetting(),
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.Transient,
    SettingsRegistration.InjectionMembers);

...

public static class SettingsRegistration
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> IsSetting(this IEnumerable<Type> types)
    {
        return types.Where(type => !type.IsAbstract && 
                                   typeof (ISettings).IsAssignableFrom(type));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<InjectionMember> InjectionMembers(Type type)
    {
        return new[] {new InjectionFactory(LoadSetting)};
    }

    public static ISettings LoadSetting(IUnityContainer container, 
                                        Type type, 
                                        string name)
    {
        var svc = (ISettings) container.Resolve(type, name);
        return svc.LoadSetting(type);
    }
}
```

---

### Option 3

Or you could create a class derived from RegistrationConvention and let that class make all of the registration decisions...

```
container.RegisterTypes(new SettingsRegistrationConvention(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies()));

...

public class SettingsRegistrationConvention : RegistrationConvention
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Type> _scanTypes;

    public SettingsRegistrationConvention(IEnumerable<Type> scanTypes)
    {
        if (scanTypes == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("scanTypes");

        _scanTypes = scanTypes;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> GetTypes()
    {
        return _scanTypes.Where(type => !type.IsAbstract && 
                                        typeof (ISettings).IsAssignableFrom(type));
    }

    public override Func<Type, IEnumerable<Type>> GetFromTypes()
    {
        return WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces;
    }

    public override Func<Type, string> GetName()
    {
        return WithName.Default;
    }

    public override Func<Type, LifetimeManager> GetLifetimeManager()
    {
        return WithLifetime.Transient;
    }

    public override Func<Type, IEnumerable<InjectionMember>> GetInjectionMembers()
    {
        return type => new[]
        {
            new InjectionFactory((c, t, n) =>
            {
                var svc = (ISettings) c.Resolve(t);
                return svc.LoadSetting(t);
            })
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Really nice answer! Thanks for this : )))