# Register all class that implements IValidator<SomethingValidatable> with Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Suppose I defined some validation logic like this:

```
public class Rule1 : IValidator<SomethingValidatable>
{
    public IList<Error> Validate(SomethingValidatable item) 
    {
         // apply validation logic to item
    }
}
```

Somewhere in code I bind `IValidator<SomethingValidatable>` to one or more concrete `Rule`:

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container
        .RegisterType<IValidator<SomethingValidatable>, Rule1>("a")
        .RegisterType<IValidator<SomethingValidatable>, Rule2>("b");
}
```

and where I need this validation occurs I have somethin like:

```
public class HereIValidateClass 
{
    private readonly IValidator<SomethingValidatable>[] validators;

    public HereIValidateClass(IValidator<SomethingValidatable>[] validators)
    {
        this.validators = validators;
    }

    public IList<Error> DoSomething() 
    {
        foreach (var validator in validators)
        {
            var errors = validator.Validate(something);
            // append to IList<Error>
        }

        return errors;
    }
}
```

This do the job. But I would avoid to register explicitely one by one each rules. I really like to say: *Dear Unity, register each class in a given namespace that implements `IValidator<SomethingValidatable>`*.

Comment: Take a look at this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27372032/1504480). It's regarding registration by convention.

Comment: @BAD_SEED, The first answer using extension methods works for me. Did it work for you as well? If yes, please mark it as "accepted". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about an extension method for IUnityContainer:

```
public static class UnityExtensions
{
    public static void RegisterValidators(this IUnityContainer container)
    {
        var types = AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().GetValidators();
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            var interfaces = WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces(type);
            foreach (var @interface in interfaces)
            {
                container.RegisterType(@interface, type);
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetValidators(this IEnumerable<Type> types)
    {
        var wantedType = typeof(IValidator<>);
        return from type in types 
               from interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces() 
               where interfaceType.IsGenericType 
                    && !interfaceType.ContainsGenericParameters 
                    && wantedType.IsAssignableFrom(interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) 
               select type;
    }
}
```

And if you need more info about the specific registrations you can use an attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MyValidationAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string RegistrationName { get; set; }

    public MyValidationAttribute(string name)
    {
        RegistrationName = name;
    }
}
```

And then change the extension method to something like this:

```
    public static void RegisterValidators(this IUnityContainer container)
    {
        var types = AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().GetValidators();
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            var interfaces = WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces(type);
            foreach (var @interface in interfaces)
            {
                var myAttr = type.GetCustomAttributes<MyValidationAttribute>(false);
                foreach (var attr in myAttr)
                {
                    // Register with specific name.
                    container.RegisterType(@interface, type, attr.RegistrationName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And change your registration:

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterValidators();
}
```

It will register each implementation for `IValidator`, regardless of T.